# Copying an element of a list to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, list, clone

I'm trying to iterate through all the elements in listname1(a list containing 2d arrays) while storing them in a 2D array. However, I don't think the array is being updated. I think the issue is that I'm getting a deep copy but I'm trying to create a new instances and use clone but it isn't working.

```
public class MainMap implements Cloneable {
    List listname1;
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        MainMap m = new MainMap();
        m.listname1 = this.listname1;
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // listname1 is a variable from a different class so I couldn't 
        // listname1 is a list containing multiple 2d arrays
        // array is a 2d array
        listname1 = classname.method(foo); 
        for (int i = 0; i < listname1.size(); i++) {
            List <int [][]> listname2 = new ArrayList <int [][]>(listname1.clone());
            int [][] array = (int [][]) listname2.get(i).clone();

            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

listname1 is defined in another class, sorry if the names are confusing. Effectively what the method does is make different formations of a given list then returns it. This method also uses clone successfully to get a shallow copy.

```
public List listName1(List randomlist, int [] array1, int [][] 2DArray, int [][] prev2DArray)
{

    int x = array1[0] - 1; 
    int y = array1[1] - 1;
    List listName1 = new ArrayList();

    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
        {

            if (neighbourNodes.contains(2DArray[i][j]))
            {

                int temp = 2DArray[i][j];
                int temp2 = 2DArray[x][y];
                2DArray[i][j] = temp2;
                2DArray[x][y] = temp;// 
                int[][] cloned2DArray = new int[2DArray[0].length][2DArray[1].length];

                for (int t = 0; t < 2DArray.length; t++) {
                    cloned2DArray[t] = 2DArray[t].clone();
                }

                if (!(old2Darray== cloned2DArray))
                {
                    listName1.add(cloned2DArray);
                }

                2DArray[i][j] = temp;
                2DArray[x][y] = temp2;
            } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem may also be adding contents from a 3d list into a 2d array

Comment: Is there more to MainMap than you are showing. You appear to return a non-initialized listname1 at the end of clone.

Comment: listname1 is initialised at the top outside the methods

Comment: You use the term "deep copy" in your question but that is not what you are doing with  m.listname1 = this.listname1; inside the clone method. All of your listname1 objects will point to the same list. Is that what you want? Do you really want to iterate through each element in the list and make a new object occupying distinct memory with the same values into each new clone. That is what is considered a deep copy. You are doing a shallow copy. Share the initialization code for listname1 and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: I want to iterate through through each element to modify using different elements which only deal with single 2d arrays. I'm not exactly sure if "deep copy" was the actual issue but it was extremely similar to a problem that I had before

Answer (score 0):

To do a deep clone you would need to create a whole new listname1 in your clone method:

```
public Object clone() {
    MainMap m = new MainMap();
    // NOTE: these values passed to the listname1 method need 
    // to be initialized somewhere else in the code. 
    m.listname1 = this.listname1(randomlist, array1, 2DArray, prev2DArray);
    return m;
}
```

Instead of assigning m.listname1 to point to the memory address of an existing copy of a listname you will initialize a brand new copy in memory with whatever starting values you want. I think this solves what you are looking to do but let me know if it does not. Note the key distinction here is that you are creating a whole new object in memory instead of merely pointing to an existing copy that is essentially shared among all the clones. So if one clone changes that mutual object the change is reflected among all clone copies. Doing what I suggest will create copies that are independent from each other.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear but I do want to point to different elements in listname1. For example, list name may have 3 2d arrays I want each individual 2d array to go through the loop until there are no more arrays left

Comment: Is this a school project? If so can you point me to the assignment (is it online?) so I can understand what you are trying to solve here.

Comment: Yh Im basically doing a bfs to solve the 9 puzzle problem and listname 1 is the boards on a given level

Comment: This? https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=2508

Comment: I've actually fixed the issue and it had nothing to do with the clone, sorry to have wasted your time.